# jsp select dropdown not coming one list

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

[image: font-end showing this way]

here is code I want dropdown in one list

```html
<%@page import="devesh.com.*,java.util.*"%>
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="OutBagAction.jsp">

<%
ArrayList<Bag> list=BagWorker.getAllBag();



%>
<center>
<font face="Times new roman">ItemCode
<%
for(Bag ba:list)
{
int itemcode=ba.getItemcode();
%>
<select name ="itemCode">
<tr>
<option><%= ba.getItemcode()%></option></tr>
</select>
<% } %>
<br><br>

<font face="Times new roman">SampleBy <input type="text" name="sampleBy">
<br><br>
<font face="Times new roman">Color <input type="text" name="color">
<br><br>
<font face="Times new roman">Quantity <input type="text" name="quantity">
<br><br>
<font face="Time new roman">OutDate <input type="date" name="outDate">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Out Bag"></center>

</body>
</html>
```

I want dropdown in one, list what can I do for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your code. Assuming you are getting your list in JSP.

```
 <select name="itemCode">
   <c:forEach items="${list}" var="value">
     <option value="${value}">
      ${value}
     </option>
   </c:forEach>
  </select>
```

Currently you are creating select for each value that is the issue. You have to declare the select box once and append all the values to it.

You can correct your code by moving
`<select name ="itemCode">` outside of for-loop.

Comment: **Thanks so much dude**